# Decode RubyEncoder

Tags: deobfuscation, script

I was trying out some things when I came across some RubyEncoder encoded code.
After searching the web, I found basically nothing useful on how to reverse them (Except [this](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/318464) and [this][2], but I had no success until now).
Is there any way to do it? If yes, how?